# Странная граница кнопки в Opera

Tags: css3, html, css

Есть [сайт](http://deaphome.com/index1.php), точнее я пока его только делаю. Так вот, есть какой-то баг. Дело вот в чем. Если `input` поиска получает фокус, то кнопка рядом обрамляется черной границей, при чем это происходит только в опере (у меня 11.52). В лисе, гугле, и даже ослике такого не наблюдаю. Может, кто подскажет, в чем проблема? Или это просто баг оперы?

Comment: Забавно. А попробуйте вырубить автокомплит на input поиска. Т.е уберите евент onFocus.

Comment: автокомплит не по фокусу. Вот без него `http://demo.versal.cn.ua/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже это таки "фича" оперы, подсвечивать сабмит формы. Если поменять submit на button - то всё ок.

Comment: Ну сабмит по js - не проблема. А на счет враппера не понял... В вашем примере я наблюдаю тот же самый эффект.

Comment: Поэтому я его удалил :) 

Суть примерно такова:

`обернуть кнопку дополнительным элементом, задать самой кнопке border: none, а обёртке соответствующий border и border-radius.`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" />
```

И нет проблем! При условии что проверочным в отправке формы будет какое нибудь hidden поле!

Comment: Изображения в качестве функциональных элементов формы не признаю. Если я конечно правильно вас понял.

Comment: Я тоже в своих взглядах много чего не признаю, но если оно работает значит это хорошо!